# missing something with autentication in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

**PYTHON:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class Firstapp(View):

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'index.html')

    def post(self, request):

        username = request.POST['your_name']
        user = authenticate(username=username)
        return HttpResponse(user)
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

<input type="text" name ='your_name' placeholder="username"/>
<button type="submit">Button</button>
```

I have created many users: admin, user_one, user_two etc. Checked via /admin page and usernames are there as they should be. Followed by documentantion in Django I wrote the code, however I don't understand why submiting a username which is in database returns none in Fistapp.post? like authnetication(username='user_one') returns None. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: A password would help.

Comment: Is Passowrd a must?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default Django backend to authenticate, a password would be required

If what you needs is a authentication without password, I recommend you read [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/)

Django would always returns None if has an invalid authentication